# adding a node to a nodeQueue on creation

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

How can I automatically add a node to a specific nodeQueue when this is created (I'm using nodeQueue module: http://drupal.org/project/nodequeue).

The reason is that I want an sortable (by dragging the nodes) list of the nodes and I want them to be automatically added to it..

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3529874/drupal-automatically-add-new-nodes-to-a-nodequeue/10483181#10483181

I tried this and it worked. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. there are modules to create nodequeue for terms, you can create nodequeues with preloaded nodes with those modules
2. you can add a trigger and write your own logic to select and insert nodes
3. if you just want to test the nodequeue, just type on the interface, the auto-complete field is very friendly

Comment: thanks. Can I automatically include all nodes of a "Content Type" (Like in Views rather than using a trigger ?) thanks

Comment: the simplest way i can come up is to write a simple script that pull the data and insert into queue with nodequeue_save();
you can find examples at: http://drupal.org/node/293117

Answer (score 0):

Triggers and Actions, and maybe the workflow module should let you automate this.  See http://www.drupal.org.uk/node/259

Answer (score 0):

Try these functions:

- `nodequeue_get_all_qids()` give us the avaliable $qid's
- `nodequeue_load ($qid)`
- `nodequeue_load_subqueues_by_queue($qid)` give us $sqid's
- `nodequeue_load_subqueue ($sqid)` load a subqueue the sqiu is exactly that same as qid
- `nodequeue_subqueue_add($queue, $subqueue, $nid)` - that is able to add the nid to queue :)